# How to delete an item from storage in FlatList?

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I've got strings in my storage and I'd like to create a delete button that would delete a key in my storage. My issue is that I'm in a flatList and I can't manage to make it work.

```
async removeItemValue(key) {
try {
  await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
  return true;
}
catch(exception) {
  return false;
}
```

}

```
render() {
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.imgData}
      renderItem={({item}) => 
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", marginBottom: 20, borderBottomColor:"white", borderBottomWidth:1}}>
          <Text>{item.date}</Text>
          <Image style={{width: 300, height: 350}} source={{ uri: item.key }} />
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menuButton} onPress={this.removeItemValue(item.key)}>
            <Text>Delete</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View> 
      }
    />
  </View>
</View>
);
```

}
}

Can you please explain to me also why the OnPress method in the touchableOpacity is called when this page is loaded and not only when the button is clicked?

Comment: Below answers are correct, but keep in mind, your list won't update because it is still rendering the state data. Don't forget to update state after `removeItemValue` resolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you define the prop you send in as a **(arrow) function**:

```
onPress={() => this.removeItemValue(item.key)}
```

If you send in the prop like this...

```
 onPress={this.removeItemValue(item.key)}
```

...then you no longer send in a function, but the **value** that the function this.removeItemValue(...) returns. The function is executed before passing it in to the component.

Answer (score 2):

regarding `onPress`, you call the function while compile. `onPress={this.removeItemValue(item.key)}`. you have to send a callback there, like this:

`onPress={() => {console.log("pressed")}}`

In your case
`onPress={() => {this.removeItemValue(item.key)}}`

Answer (score 1):

replace your render method to this

```
render() {
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.imgData}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => 
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", marginBottom: 20, borderBottomColor:"white", borderBottomWidth:1}}>
          <Text>{item.date}</Text>
          <Image style={{width: 300, height: 350}} source={{ uri: item.key }} />
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menuButton} onPress={() => this.removeItemValue(item.key)}>
            <Text>Delete</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View> 
      }
    />
  </View>
</View>
);
```

while in mapping you need to callback using arrow function

if you want to delete any value from array object pass `index` in onPress button so you can delete easily any value using index.

- make sure once you delete value from storage please update your state
  because you have render state in flatlist and you delete from storage.